# Is there any rule of thumb to optimize sql queries like this

Tags: db2

this is my first question here. Although I've been helped out from this forum over a hundred times.
I was having difficulties in optimizing sql query. It takes hours to execute. Record set is also large enough. The query was not written by me. So just to find the bottle neck I tried removing conditional clauses but that doesn't make any difference. Indexing the ID's done.

Can any sql guru here could throw some light on it. Is there any fine tuning room left in the query below? The server hosting the database in DB2. I'm not too pro in sql.
Thanks as always.
Regards, Nuh

This is the query:

```
SELECT
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RISK_DETAIL_ID ,
POLICY_RISK_COVER.RISK_COVER_ID ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_POLICY_SYSTEM_NO ,
RD_POLICY_END_NO_IDX ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_POLICY_ID ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_LEVEL1_ID ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_SUM_INSURED_AMT_LC ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_PREMIUM_AMT_LC ,
POLICY_RISK_COVER.PREMIUM_AMOUNT_FC ,
POLICY_RISK_COVER.SUM_INSURED_AMT_FC ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_REC_TYPE ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_EFFECT_FROM_DT ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_EFFECT_TO_DT ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_END_EFFECT_FROM_DT ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.SEX_MAS_CD ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.MARITAL_STATUS_CD ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.EMP_CATG ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.NO_OF_DEPENDENTS ,
CAST((
CASE 
    WHEN HEALTH_INSURANCE.AUTHORITY_LETTER_NO IS NULL 
    THEN HEALTH_INSURANCE.EMP_AL_NO 
    ELSE HEALTH_INSURANCE.AUTHORITY_LETTER_NO 
END) AS INT) AS EMP_AL_NO ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.DOB ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.EFF_DATE ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.EFF_DATE2 ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.NAME ,
CAST((SUBSTR(HEALTH_INSURANCE.RELATIONSHIP_CD, 5,2)) AS INT) AS 
RELATIONSHIP_CD_S ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.RELATIONSHIP_CD ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.DESIGNATION ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.BRANCH ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.BANK_ACCOUNT ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.BANK_BRANCH_NAME ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.PRE_EXISTING_AILMENT ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.AUTHORITY_LETTER_NO ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.AGE ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.REGION ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.CNIC ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.CO_CODE ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.EMP_LOCATION ,
HEALTH_INSURANCE.SUB_LOCATION ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CLH_SYSTEM_NO ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_SYS_ID ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_POL_SYS_ID ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_END_NO_IDX ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_END_SR_NO ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_CATEGORY ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_SYS_ID ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLDH_SYS_ID ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_COVER_CD ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_END_IDX ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_COVER_DESC ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_TYPE_LIMIT ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_REL ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_AGE_FROM ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_AGE_TO ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_RB_LIMIT ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CATEGORY_LIMIT_FC ,
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CATEGORY_PREM_FC 
FROM
DB2ADMIN.HEALTH_INSURANCE AS HEALTH_INSURANCE 
    INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.POLICY_RISK_COVER AS POLICY_RISK_COVER 
    ON HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_POLICY_SYSTEM_NO = POLICY_RISK_COVER.
    RC_POLICY_SYSTEM_NO AND
    TRIM(RD_LEVEL1_ID) = TRIM(RC_LEVEL1_ID) 
        INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER AS CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER 
        ON HEALTH_INSURANCE.RD_POLICY_ID = CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.
        CTH_POL_SYS_ID AND
        HEALTH_INSURANCE.EMP_CATG = CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_CATEGORY 
            INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL AS 
            CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL 
            ON CATEGORY_LIMIT_HEADER.CTH_SYS_ID = CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.
            CLDH_SYS_ID AND
            POLICY_RISK_COVER.RISK_COVER_CD = CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.
            CLD_COVER_CD AND
            HEALTH_INSURANCE.RELATIONSHIP_CD = CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.
            CLD_CLM_REL 
WHERE
COALESCE(HEALTH_INSURANCE.AGE, 1) BETWEEN CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.
CLD_CLM_AGE_FROM AND
CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_AGE_TO
```

Comment: The first step is always to check the execution plan.

Comment: Are the other JOIN columns like RISK_COVER_CD indexed? Have you tried it without the TRIM function?
Also test the query with a subset of the data. Maybe you have already done that.

Comment: Can you let us know the approx no of records for each of the tables involved please.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hi mate, how can I check the execution plan?

Comment: @Wietze314: Yes, joining members are indexed. I haven't tried it without the trim function. Will do that now. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisProsser: The records are quite much. Aprox 10,00,000+ per table. Its actually a Warehouse's table.

Comment: One more question. Roughly what proportion of the records to you expect the query to return i.e. after the where clause what % of the records do you expect to remain? Just a rough estimate is fine.

Comment: Hi again Chris, I think the query will return aprox 30% of the total volume of data. Its just a rough thought based on other similar cases I have here in this DataWH. And I'm unable to see the result of this query up til now, so cant say any figure for sure. P.S.: For the number of records, I just asked a former member, he said that Health Line of Business is the biggest going more than 10,000,000 records. :|

Comment: I have more experience with oracle than DB2, in Oracle you can often find that if you are retrieving > around 15% of the table it can sometimes be quicker to do full table scans than using an index. Indexes are very good at finding a small number of records quickly, but not so good for big jobs like this. I have been looking round for syntax on optimiser hints, but it looks like DB2 uses a concept of optimiser profiles rather than hints. Anyway, if you get the chance I would suggest trying this query without using the indexes and in parallel mode so that the load will be spread.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you so much for the insight. I will definitely try to re-run the query with the indexes removed. Will post back then.

Comment: Which DB2 platform are you using, DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?  Tuning can be different among those three platforms.  And tuning for Oracle is *entirely* different.

Comment: @ChrisProsser This is a data warehouse.  Other applications are likely to need whatever indexes exist.  The optimizer will evaluate the indexes and statistics to decide for itself if a table scan is better.    If anything you would want to create the perfect indexes, which may be suggested by the index advisor.

Comment: @WarrenT Sorry, this wasn't clear enough. What I actually meant was to try running this query without using the indexes not to remove existing indexes from the database altogether. I'm not sure what is the best way to do this in DB2, maybe just a small operation such as a +1 either side of a join using numerical data if there are no optimser hints available for this. The execution plan should make it pretty clear if this is working. Anyway, not saying that this will definitely improve performance in this case, but I have seen in work on other DBMS' in the past, so may be worth a try.

Comment: @Wietze314, You were the first to suggest to remove the TRIM function. It did the work. The execution time is remarkably reduced. Can you also tell me whats in the inside story for this TRIM? Why it was being the reason?

Answer (score 5):

Some rules of thumb that might be relevant to you . . .

- Never try to tune a query without a representative EXPLAIN plan. *Representative* means to get an EXPLAIN plan either from the production database or from a dev/test database that have nearly the same number of rows and nearly the same distribution of values, ideally running on similar hardware. Different numbers of rows and different distribution of values often means different execution plans.
- Make sure statistics are up to date.
- Index (or verify indexes) on every column used in a JOIN clause and every column used in a WHERE clause. I think *every* dbms implements primary key constraints and foreign key constraints with indexes. There *used* to be some that wouldn't let you drop such indexes, and one or two that *would* let you. Since I deal with a lot of different dbms, I don't bother trying to remember which is which. I just look it up when I need to know. So just look it up.
- One multi-column index might perform better than three single-column indexes. Think about consolidating indexes.
- Write sargable WHERE clauses. Your expression `COALESCE(HEALTH_INSURANCE.AGE, 1) BETWEEN one_column AND another_column` has to evaluate the COALESCE() function for every row--it can't use an index. If it's possible, replace the NULLs with the literal integer 1, and make that column non-nullable. (This isn't always practical, but non-sargable WHERE clauses are often a performance killer, especially if other considerations provoke a full table scan.)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the best indexes available to support your query.

1) If you are using **DB2 for IBM i** or **z/OS**, then you can create indexes based on expressions.  If you are using DB2 for LUW, then it seems you don't have this feature (at least as of v10.1):

If you cannot join properly without using `trim()`, then consider creating an indexes on RD_POLICY_SYSTEM_NO, RD_LEVEL1_ID, TRIM(RD_LEVEL1_ID), and another on RC_POLICY_SYSTEM_NO, RC_LEVEL1_ID, TRIM(RC_LEVEL1_ID), or some variation of this concept.

2) If you are using **DB2 for IBM i**:

If you have low cardinality on some join columns, such as code values, then consider creating  [Encoded Vector Indexes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajq%2Fwhentouseevis.htm) [EVI's].  You might, for example create an EVI on RD_LEVEL_ID.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the BETWEEN in your where clause to

```
COALESCE(HEALTH_INSURANCE.AGE, 1) >= CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_AGE_FROM 
AND COALESCE(HEALTH_INSURANCE.AGE, 1) < CATEGORY_LIMIT_DETAIL.CLD_CLM_AGE_TO+1
```

In my experience this has been faster than between over large record sets. YMMV.

Comment: I would really hope that the optimiser would be smart enough to know that these are the effectively the same thing.

Comment: I second Chris, based on my readings regarding similar questions being answered here. Although to minimize the doubt I tried that suggestion.

Comment: This has been an urban legend since ages. I don't know any DBMS where the claim is true that `between` is slower than the corresponding `>=` and `<=`. (Btw `betwee` is *inclusive* on both ends, so you should at least have used `<=` not `<`)

Comment: It is inclusive on both ends, there is a +1 at the end.  I have seen speedups on very large sets of data, more on date fields then on other types.  OP asked for fine tuning suggestions.

Comment: So you are saying that incrementing a value+1 and using `<` is faster than merely comparing with `<=`?? Why? Is DB2 evaluating `<` seperately from `=`??  How about `NOT( a > b )` instead?

Comment: Honestly, that is a holdover from using this for Datetime comparisons, +1 ensures that the timestamp does not interfere with the date you want, my overall point was that I have found the regular operators to be slightly faster than BETWEEN

Answer (score 0):

One rule of thumb is to not use functions in your where clause like this:

```
where function(field) = something.
```

That sort of construct will always be slower than using the field directly.

Comment: Understood, I guess you are referring to the COALESCE function. I'll try to sort that out with the advice given by 'CatCall'

Comment: Joining on TRIM(RD_LEVEL1_ID) = TRIM(RC_LEVEL1_ID) would be another place.

Comment: Hi Warren, I just removed TRIM from the query and the runtime reduces 10 times! Additionally I also removed COALESCE (Added it back in ETL process) And again the runtime reduces a little more. Now its totally affordable query-time. Thanks ti you and Everyone who helped me out. Just for the learning, why that TRIM function was being the bottle neck to the whole query? Whats the catch inside?